# What is the cleanest way to make a dynamic list of buttons in asp.net?

Tags: asp.net

I want to change this list so that it is dynamically populated:

```
<ul>
 <li id="Tab1" class="selected" runat="server">
     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" OnClick="LinkButton1_Click"runat="server">
         Tab1 Text
     </asp:LinkButton>
 </li>
 <li id="Tab2" runat="server">
     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" OnClick="LinkButton2_Click" runat="server">
         Tab2 Text
     </asp:LinkButton>
 </li>
 <li id="Tab3" runat="server">
     <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" OnClick="LinkButton3_Click" runat="server">
         Tab3 Text
     </asp:LinkButton>
 </li>
</ul>
```

I tried using this code:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView_Tabs" OnItemCommand="ListView_ChangeTab" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton Text='<%# Eval("displayName") %>' CommandName='<%# Eval("parameterName") %>' runat="server"/>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

and populate it in code behind:

```
  ListView_Tabs.DataSource = comeClass.GetTabs();
  ListView_Tabs.DataBind();
```

But I don't see any clear way to set class='selected' to the last link I clicked ( or rather the list item that contains the link )

So my question is

**What is the cleanest way to make a dynamic list of buttons in asp.net, or even just in .net?**

It doesn't have to be anything like my approach. I'm not even sure using ListView is the best approach to solve this.

Comment: What is the problem you're facing when you try to set the class to the last link?

Comment: What "problem" did you have when trying to set class="selected"?  How did you try to do so?

Comment: And how exactly are you setting class='selected'? From markup, or are you doing something else?

Comment: The problem is a lack of comming up with a clear way of doing it more than me running into a problem while I'm trying to do it.

Comment: My imagined approach is to add class='selected' to the Listview Item that threw the click event. But I don't see any clean way of doing this.

Comment: Are you saying that the clicked item should have the class="selected" added AFTER it has been clicked (ie: the page loads with no classes added?)

Comment: What? :) What am I not understanding? I want to manipulate the ListView before it is rendered. And I would expect the ListView to be rendered according to the current state of the listview. So it is a big surprise to me to learn, and see on my screen now, that the class='selected' is added AFTER the page loads.

Comment: @Alison I would like to add class = 'selected' to the listItem containing the clicked button so the user sees what button he just clicked on the next postback. The implementation is not restricted at all. Just want to find a clean solution. Im currently experimenting with SelectedItemTemplate suggested by @Dillie-O  The selectedIndexChang happens too late it seems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can leverage the SelectedItemTemplate and SelectedIndex attributes of your ListView to accomplish this.

Change the CommandName property to "Select" in your ListItemTemplate. That way when the the postback occurs, the ListView will have the row index of the LinkButton you selected. You can then set your custom command to the CommandArgument paramter for any custom processing when the ItemSelected event is raised by clicking the LinkButton.

Then in your SelectedItemTemplate, you can apply the class right there. Your ListView would look something like this:

```
<asp:ListView ID="ListView_Tabs" OnItemCommand="ListView_ChangeTab" runat="server">
    <LayoutTemplate>
        <div class="tabs">
            <ul>
                <li id="itemPlaceholder" runat="server" />
            </ul>
        </div>
    </LayoutTemplate>
    <ItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton Text='<%# Eval("displayName") %>' CommandName="Select"  CommandArgument='<%# Eval("parameterName") %>' runat="server"/>
        </li>
    </ItemTemplate>
    <SelectedItemTemplate>
        <li>
            <asp:LinkButton Text='<%# Eval("displayName") %>' CommandName="Select" CommandArgument='<%# Eval("parameterName") %>' CssClass="selected" runat="server"/>
        </li>
    </SelectedItemTemplate>
</asp:ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the ItemDataBound event for that and set the selected class there.
You would identify the selected item with the CommandParameter.
Compare the e.DataItem to a property of the item you set as the CommandParameter.

So you would have something like this in the ItemDataBoud:

```
YourClass item = e.Item.DataItem as YourClass;
if(item == null) return;
if(item.YourKeyProp == e.CommandArgument)
{
Literal classlit = e.Item.FindControl("classLiteral") as Literal;
if(classlit == null) return:
classlit.Text = "Selected";
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Use a Repeater instead:

```
<ul>
<asp:Repeater runat="server">
<ItemTemplate>
<li>
    <asp:LinkButton runat="server" CommandName='' CommandArgument='' Text='' />
</li>
</ItemTemplate>
</asp:Repeater></ul>
```

Comment: Repeater is lighter weight, and is what I use to simply repeat items. It has no header or footer capabilities, for example. Since your question mentions "cleanest", this is relevant.

Comment: How would you add class='selected' to the <li> that contains the link that was clicked?

Comment: You can have access any control in ItemTemplate block in ItemDataBound event.